# Openlayers edit with zoom

Tags: javascript, openlayers, gis

I am working with Openlayers, and I want to modify a feature, but there seems to be an issue with zoom level 17, as it works perfectly at zoom level 16.

zoom 16

[image]

zoom 17

[image]

As shown in the image, at zoom level 17, the editing handles and the polygon do not coincide.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Is there any chance that you could put a working example in jsFiddle, as it is impossible to diagnose from the information you have provided. Let me know if you need any help setting up openlayers with jsFiddle.

Comment: Thank you for reply, sorry ,  it is impossible to use jsFiddle

Comment: I have worked on the modify feature code quite a bit, with some huge polygons (20,000+ points), without seeing as issues. I would like to help you, but without seeing your example working, there isn't much I can do.

Comment: I have dynamic data, use geoserver and other app server for data , what's why  i can not provide real time example for you, i can show you how to create map and geoserver feature manager request

Comment: OK, I understand that, but it must be something specific about that polygon and your zoom level 17. If you could save that polygon as WKT or GeoJSON, then it would be possible to replicate the problem in jsFiddle, perhaps?

Comment: No,there is no specific anything zoom level 17, I think I have irregular polygon ,for example polygon with  self-intersection.Is it problem?There is fragment of my polygon 
P.s I used GeoJson format

Comment: I am pretty sure that OpenLayers doesn't check for self-intersecting polygons, as I once had to write such a check myself. If you save your polygon as GeoJSON and put it on jsFiddle using http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Format/GeoJSON-js.html to read it, I will see if I can fix your issue.

Comment: Are there any problem about big geometry to edit?

Comment: Not that I am aware of. In my experience, it will be very slow with a large polygon, but drawn correctly.

Comment: It is critical problem for me, could you help me via teamviewer? (i am sorry if this comment is incorrect)

Comment: Not via teamviewer, but if you put your polygon on github (or something similar), I will happily look into it.

Comment: Thank you very much, i try to do something

Comment: My projection is  projection: new OpenLayers.Projection('EPSG:4326'), Is there any problem about big zoom , might I need other projection higth zoom

Comment: /**
     * Constant: MAX_PIXEL
     * {Integer} Firefox has a limitation where values larger or smaller than  
     *           about 15000 in an SVG document lock the browser up. This 
     *           works around it.
     */
    MAX_PIXEL: 15000,  this is solution, my polygon is big  and mixel > 15000  i change size but it will not work for firefox. Please write answer and i will accept

Comment: Well done for finding that, I have never noticed that with Firefox before. I have posted an answer that allows you to simplify a polygon until you reach a certain number of points, maybe this will help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing you could do to get round the number of points limitation with the SVG renderer in Firefox would be to call simplify on the Polygon. See the simplify function here, http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/browser/trunk/openlayers/lib/OpenLayers/Geometry/LineString.js, which is based on the Douglas-Peucker algorithm. The simplify function takes a Linestring as an argument, so you would have to call simplify several times until you reach a number below 15,000 and then recreate the Polygon.

I have put an example of how to do this on jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/u6Yfg/

```
var polygon='POLYGON((x1 y1, x2, y2......xn,yn))'

//convert wkt to OpenLayers.Feature.Vector
var reader=new OpenLayers.Format.WKT();
var feat=reader.read(polygon);

//get initial points from feature's geometry and set target points (eg, 200 here).
var num_points=feat.geometry.components[0].components.length;
var target_points=200;

//set simplification tolerance to one meter initially
var tolerance=1;

//convert feature's geometry to linestring
var linestring=new OpenLayers.Geometry.LineString(feat.geometry.components[0].components);
var simplified_linestring;

//simplify linestring until target points reached
while(target_points<num_points){
    simplified_linestring=linestring.simplify(tolerance);
    num_points=simplified_linestring.components.length;
    tolerance+=1;
}


alert('Number of points in simplified geometry: ' + simplified_linestring.components.length);

//create new geometry from simplified linestring    
var geom=new OpenLayers.Geometry.Polygon(new OpenLayers.Geometry.LinearRing(simplified_linestring.components));
```